# Cannot shrink lvm2 partition

Tags: centos, filesystems, partition, lvm

I have a need to shrink lvm2 partition, that was created by CentOS 7.4 installer. I am confused with what I see by lvm commands:

**pvdisplay**

```
root@ubuntu:/home/ubuntu# pvdisplay
  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/sdb2
  VG Name               sample-group
  PV Size               28.32 GiB / not usable 3.00 MiB
  Allocatable           yes (but full)
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              7250
  Free PE               0
  Allocated PE          7250
  PV UUID               xutuoL-6546d-rttert-n7tH-eeXu-24t3-dgf33
```

**vgdisplay**

```
root@ubuntu:/home/ubuntu# vgdisplay
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               sample-group
  System ID            
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  3
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                2
  Open LV               0
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               28.32 GiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              7250
  Alloc PE / Size       7250 / 28.32 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       0 / 0  
  VG UUID               ytjytj-QWT5-sdf-vSMj-rKtj-gfhdfh-76885
```

**lvdisplay**

```
root@ubuntu:/home/ubuntu# lvdisplay
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/sample-group/swap
  LV Name                swap
  VG Name                sample-group
  LV UUID                JIZL0D-kNfL-aEsR-y6Rl-1mzx-wWpO-ngcElh
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time cube, 2018-04-20 07:15:29 +0000
  LV Status              available
  # open                 0
  LV Size                2.93 GiB
  Current LE             751
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:0

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/sample-group/root
  LV Name                root
  VG Name                sample-group
  LV UUID                4OIJBb-6MSa-y5Ua-62bI-O6Lf-pjWZ-Qnz4Gv
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time cube, 2018-04-20 07:15:30 +0000
  LV Status              suspended
  # open                 0
  LV Size                25.39 GiB
  Current LE             6499
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:1
```

From the above output we see that there is totally no free space on the disk, but this is what I see in file-manager:

[image]

Almost the whole disk is empty, but why it lies me in console?

I cannot estimate how much space do I have and cannot shrink it. Tried with kvpm and it shows the same.

**UPDATE:**
After the Emmanuel's manipulations on `parted resizepart` step it throws

```
 Error: can't have the end before the start (start sector=2099200 length=-2073809)
```

And here is what **pvs/vgs** shows:

```
 PV         VG           Fmt  Attr PSize  PFree
 /dev/sdb2  sample-group lvm2 a--  4.00g  1.06g
```

**UPDATE 2:**

Successfully resized the partition, but now xfsdump refuses to restore my filesystem:

```
xfsdump: using file dump (drive_simple) strategy
xfsdump: version 3.1.6 (dump format 3.0) - type ^C for status and control

xfsdump: WARNING: most recent level 0 dump was interrupted, but not resuming that dump since resume (-R) option not specified
xfsdump: level 0 dump of ubuntu:/mnt/root
xfsdump: dump date: Sat May 26 18:14:53 2018
xfsdump: session id: 2c905a06-6e7d-400e-8a03-5e0e20ea4583
xfsdump: session label: "new"
xfsdump: ino map phase 1: constructing initial dump list
xfsdump: ino map phase 2: skipping (no pruning necessary)
xfsdump: ino map phase 3: skipping (only one dump stream)
xfsdump: ino map construction complete
xfsdump: estimated dump size: 20800 bytes
xfsdump: positioned at media file 0: dump 0, stream 0
xfsdump: ERROR: media contains valid xfsdump but does not support append
xfsdump: dump size (non-dir files) : 0 bytes
xfsdump: NOTE: dump interrupted: 8 seconds elapsed: may resume later using -R option
xfsdump: Dump Summary:
xfsdump:   stream 0 /media/ubuntu/SYSTEM/root.backup ERROR (operator error or resource exhaustion)
xfsdump: Dump Status: INTERRUPT
```

Comment: LVM does not deal with any filesystems on it.

Comment: But [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/262541/how-to-display-used-devices-free-space-when-using-lvm) they say one can use those commands for showing free space. What does `PFree` coumn is used for?

Comment: Free space in the LVM structures. The filesystems are not part of that structure.

Comment: So what would be the correct way to shrink those partition? I tried GParted but it doesn't support LVM.

Comment: First you shrink the filesystems, then you shrink the LVs, then you shrink the VG, then you shrink the PV, then you shrink the partition.

Comment: `First you shrink the filesystems` shrinking partition with `resize2fs` will result in increasing of `Free PE` value in pvs/vgs/lvs?

Comment: No. The filesystem is not part of the LVM structures.

Comment: This message, "_WARNING: Device /dev/sdb2 has size of 29005091 sectors which is smaller than corresponding PV size of 59398144 sectors. Was device resized? One or more devices used as PVs in VG sample-group have changed sizes._" means that it's really quite likely you've got corrupted filesystems. I do hope you have a backup.

Comment: I've done backup with `dd`, but dunno if I done it before or after corruption :) How can I fix that stuff? Does lvm have built-in commands for check/verify/fix filesystem?

Comment: The first thing you need to do is run a filesystem check. If the filesystem is corrupted, then there's no point in doing anything else. The filesystem will need to be unmounted for this, so boot your CentOS live CD/DVD and then you can run: `xfs_check /dev/sample-group/root`. See https://linux.die.net/man/8/xfs_check

Comment: **xfs_ncheck** gives `can't determine device size`

Comment: @Suncatcher, it sounds like your filesystem is corrupted. Give `xfs_repair` a shot: https://linux.die.net/man/8/xfs_repair BTW, you can IM me on IRC (freenode) or XMPP (xmpp.co), user emmanuelrosa

Comment: @EmmanuelRosa, what IRC channel are you reside in? There are hundreds of them on freenode

Comment: @Suncatcher, True, ha ha. I'm usually in #nixos.

Comment: @EmmanuelRosa, okay, thanks Emmanuel. I repaired the filesystem with your help, now it doesn't throw any errors. What should be my steps then to shrink the partition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To shrink your LVM partition you'll need to:

1. Boot with a Linux live CD/DVD
2. Backup your XFS filesystem (shrinking XFS is not supported)
3. Shrink your logical volume
4. Shrink your physical volume
5. Shrink your partition
6. Restore your XFS filesystem

**NOTICE:**
Before you begin check your `/etc/fstab` to see how the root filesystem device is being mounted. If it's `/dev/sample-group/root` you're good to go. But if it's using a filesystem label you need to make sure you use the `-L` option with `mkfs.xfs` to specify the same label. If it's using a UUID or something like that you'll need to adjust your `/etc/fstab` once you have your new ID.

### Backup your XFS filesystem

Backup your filesystem -ideally to another device- using `xfsdump`, like this:

```
mkdir /mnt/backup
mkdir /mnt/root
mount /dev/sample-group/root /mnt/root
mount /dev/some-backup-device /mnt/backup
xfsdump -f /mnt/backup/root.backup /mnt/root
umount /mnt/root
```

### "Shrink" your logical and physical volumes, and partition

While it is possible to shrink the root logical volume with `lvreduce`, it's just easier to delete it and recreate it using the desired size. So, you'll delete the logical volume, shrink the physical volume to be just large enough to contain your remaining logical volume (swap), shrink the partition to the desired size, resize the physical volume so it uses up all the space in the partition, and finally recreate the logical volume. I know that seems like a lot, but it avoids having to specify the resizing units accurately, which when mismatched can lead to errors.

In this example, the target size of the new logical volume is ~10GB (3GB swap + 10GB root = 13GB partition):

```
lvremove /dev/sample-group/root
pvresize --setphysicalvolumesize 4GB /dev/sdb2
parted /dev/sdb resizepart 2 13GiB
pvresize /dev/sdb2
lvcreate -ay -l 100%FREE -n root sample-group
```

The `100%FREE` tells `lvcreate` to use all the space remaining in the volume group, which in this example amounts to ~10GB. Adjust as necessary.

### Restore your XFS filesystem

Now you're ready to restore your XFS filesystem:

```
wipefs /dev/sample-group/root
mkfs.xfs /dev/sample-group/root
mount /dev/sample-group/root /mnt/root
xfsrestore -f /mnt/backup/root.backup /mnt/root
umount /mnt/root
umount /mnt/backup
```

Finally, cross your fingers and reboot.

Comment: Thanks you a lot, Emmanuel! I appreciate your effort. I am stuck at resizing part `parted /dev/sdb resizepart 2 13 Gib`. I updated the question.

Comment: OK, so the `end` parameter in the resizepart command is an offset from the beginning of the disk. I can't tell you which offset to use, so you'll have to run `parted /dev/sdb` to enter interactive mode. Then enter the `print` command to display your partitions; Note this won't show your logical volumes. Using the start and end numbers displayed for each partition you'll have to calculate what the new end number should be to give you the correct partition size. Then, run `resizepart [PARTITION_NUMBER] [OFFSET]`. See https://www.gnu.org/software/parted/manual/html_node/unit.html#unit

Comment: Thanks again. Now stuck on the last step, see my update.

Comment: Oh, sorry that should have been `xfsrestore` not `xfsdump`: `xfsrestore -f /mnt/backup/root.backup /mnt/root`

Comment: Finally I've succeeded! Thanks a ton! And thanks you for your patience!